# ShieldUI grid data from codebehind datatable

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, datagrid, shieldui

I implemented a jQuery gridview with ShieldUI.
The thing i am having problems with is the datasource for the grid.

Here is their example:
http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-general/basic-usage

I need to send the data from a datatable that is created in code behind.

Is it possible to send such data to ShieldDataSource?

Thank you.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Progress2.aspx.cs" Inherits="INAWebAppTest.Form.Progress2" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Shield.Web.UI" Namespace="Shield.Web.UI" TagPrefix="shield" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent2" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="FeaturedContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.shieldui.com/shared/components/latest/js/shieldui-all.min.js"></script>


    <section class="success" id="about">
        <div class="container">


            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"><h3>Progress</h3></asp:Label>
                    <div class="g-hr type_short type_simple">
                        <span class="g-hr-h">
                            <i class="fa fa-"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div style="vertical-align: top; margin-bottom: 0px; align-content: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto">
                        <asp:Button ID="LeftButton" runat="server" Text="<" class="g-btn type_primary size_small" OnClick="ibDLeft_Click" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="tbDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="tbDate_TextChanged" ReadOnly="true" Style="width: 30%; text-align: center" TextMode="SingleLine"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="RightButton" runat="server" Text=">" class="g-btn type_primary size_small" OnClick="ibDRight_Click" />

                    </div>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbDate" ErrorMessage="Odaberite datum" />

                    <shield:ShieldDataSource ID="shieldDataSource" runat="server" Data="testData"> </shield:ShieldDataSource>
                    <shield:ShieldGrid ID="ShieldGrid1" runat="server" ClientDataSourceID="shieldDataSource">
                        <Columns>
                            <shield:GridColumn Field="dfCategory" Width="70px" Title="ID"></shield:GridColumn>
                            <shield:GridColumn Field="dfActivityID" Title="Person Name"></shield:GridColumn>
                            <shield:GridColumn Field="dfActivityName" Title="Company Name"></shield:GridColumn>
                        </Columns>
                    </shield:ShieldGrid>                  
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </section>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do the following in the page load method and just set the Data property of the DataSource to testData in the aspx and it would work.

```
<shield:ShieldDataSource ID="shieldDataSource" runat="server" Data="testData"> 
    </shield:ShieldDataSource>
    <shield:ShieldGrid ID="grid" runat="server" ClientDataSourceID="shieldDataSource">
        <Sorting Enabled="true" />
        <Columns>
            <shield:GridColumn Field="Id" />
            <shield:GridColumn Field="Name" />
            <shield:GridColumn Field="Category" />
            <shield:GridColumn Field="Date" />
            <shield:GridColumn Field="Available" />
        </Columns>
    </shield:ShieldGrid>


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                var dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Category", typeof(int)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime)));
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Available", typeof(bool)));

                var row = dt.NewRow();
                row["Id"] = 1;
                row["Name"] = "test";
                row["Category"] = 2;
                row["Date"] = DateTime.Now;
                row["Available"] = true;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);

                var source = (from r in dt.AsEnumerable()
                              select new
                              {
                                  Id = r["Id"],
                                  Name = r["Name"],
                                  Category = r["Category"],
                                  Date = r["Date"],
                                  Available = r["Available"],
                              }).ToList();
                var script = "window.testData = " + Shield.Mvc.UI.Common.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(source);
                ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "TableData", script, true);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank You for your answer!
Is there a method from Shield.Web.UI that can do this line, or i have to download the ShieldUI ASP.NET MVC Trial plugins also?:
 var script = "window.testData = " + Shield.Mvc.UI.Common.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(source);

My application is a web forms app.

Comment: I have added the reference to the Shield.Mvc.UI package.

The source variable is populated correctly in code behind:
window.testData =[{dfCategory:"1",dfActivityID:"test",dfActivityName:"2"}]

But it is not being shown on the aspx page. I have updated the original question with the code from aspx page, can you please check if there is anything still missing?

Thank You!

Comment: It will be added to the aspx page in runtime, do not worry about it. Just set the Data property of the Datasource to testData(the name of the variable) as I have shown in the example.

Comment: About the serialization you can do your own serializer, the goal is to convert the list to json. Because ShieldUI has such functionality deployed and exposed (but in the Mvc part), I have used it instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could also convert your datatable into an array and assign this to the shieldDataSource.